# VIM - how to minimize tabindent on hilighted text

Tags: vim

Right now, my VIM editor tab indent has some unusual behaviour.

When I am in insert mode and press tab, the cursor indents about 3 spaces instead of a whole tab indent.  **I like this**.

When I high-light a block of text, then press `SHIFT` and  `>` simultaneously, the block of text indents an entire tab indent instead of 3 spaces behaviour like above. **I do not like this**.

How do I make the second action behave like the first action?

Comment: One is "ts" and the other is "sw", but I can't recall which is which.

Comment: `:set tabstop=3 shiftwidth=3` with an optional `expandtab` or `noexpandtab`. `shiftwidth` must be the same as `tabstop` or someone will be cursing your indents.

Answer (score 1):

Myself, I use:

```
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
```

This replaces tabs with spaces (`expandtab`), sets both the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> to 4 spaces (`shiftwidth`).  The `smarttab` settings allows for proper handling of <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> based on the `shiftwidth` value.  You can set `shiftwidth` to whatever you like.